# React - is it wrong to rerender on props change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have json data I get from database in my simple todo list. I have implemented it so I save these data in props and then pass it onto child components. The only way I use state right now is for filtering these data: (show all, show completed, show ongoing).

Now I want to add backtrace to database. Which means adding new items/deleting old ones. The problem is if I implement add button that adds new task to database it will not rerender the application automatically so the change wont show until I refresh the page.

So my question is. Is it correct approach to force call render in React in this situation? Or should I completely revamp the application and change the array of tasks which is prop now to state and update it at the same time while I update the database?

Thanks for answer :)

Comment: Would be helpful to post some code. And the correct aproach to update a component is to use setState.

Comment: Can we see some code ? It depends, but that is what the `render` is for, your props can be mapped and then it can be checked, alternatively, you could look into react promises .. As your back-end can tell react: "Hey im done"

Comment: So far I was just working with static array I have created locally for testing so I used props. Basically very similar to this example https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/LzWZvb. Now I want to add database to it and also the functions to manipulate with data in database. But the way it is right now if I add function to send data to database and change them it will not visually change anything in my application until I refresh the page.

Answer (score 0):

I think that need to rerender is based on whether the component should be updated or not. And in this case it should since there is new item.

As for moving to state I don't think that you need to rewrite your component to use state instead of props. You can just implement [shouldComponentUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) and check if list of todos has changed (be careful to not mutate the todo list prop!).

If you're using [React.PureComponent](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent) then you don't need to bother with `shouldComponentUpdate`, it will update automatically on any state or props change

Answer (score 0):

Using your data (in Json) as props for your React Function Component or Class Component is perfectly fine and frequently used.

Assuming that you use a Class Component (or just you React App component) and keep the data up-to-date in the state of that component, you could add member functions to add and delete the items. I would recommend to keep user interface in sync with your user actions, and maybe have a form submit handler to process all database changes (if this is feasible for your situation).

Comment: I am not sure if I understood you there. Are you saying that I should keep JSON data as props and create new state of main component called upToDate (for example) that would be boolean and then I would manage data throught this?     Or what did you mean by "managing JSON data in the state of the class component"?

Comment: That one-liner was a bit confusing (I removed it).  What I wanted to say is that you should use the state of the Class/App component. Initialize state (your tasks) in the constructor, and then call setState when you want to change it (when tasks are added or removed). Hope that this helps.